# Is it possible to open a markdown link in our app instead of Safari?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When you use markdown (example below) and you tap on links swift automatically closes my app and opens links in Safari but I'd like to open links in a webview inside my app, is it possible?

```
Text("Hello! Example of a markdown with a link [example](https://example.com)")
```

Comment: Maybe if you use a deep link that references your web link

Comment: The markdown doesn't really play a role, it's just a link like any other. Look into "universal links"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The SwiftUI environment includes a URL handler which, by default, opens links in Safari, but you can provide your own handler to override this.

```swift
Text("Hello! Example of a markdown with a link [example](https://example.com)")
  .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
    // ... set state that will cause your web view to be loaded...
    return .handled
  })
```

The `OpenURLAction` has to return a value of type `OpenURLAction.Result` - here, `.handled` tells the system that you have dealt with the URL yourself so the OS doesn't have to do anything else.

You could also include certain logic such that if (for example) the URLs pointed to specific hosts, you handled them, but everything else should open in Safari; in that case, you'd return `.handled` for the URLs you're taking responsibility for, and `.systemAction` for any URL where the default behaviour should be used.

Other return types include `.discarded` to tell the app to ignore the tap on the link, and a version of `.systemAction` that allows you to redefine the link that opens in Safari. I don't think either fit your use case here, though.

[This post on fivestars.blog](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/openurl-openurlaction/) goes into more detail. Also check out the [`openURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/openurl#) and [`OpenURLAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/openurlaction) documentation.