# SwiftUI, How to set a word as a button in the paragraph?

Tags: button, swiftui, ms-word, markdown, paragraph

I would like to make "here" a button on this note. Anyone could you tell me how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach is to use mark-down text with link and handle link by intercepting url.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image]

Here is main part:

```
        Text("All your information are confidential. For more information please refer to [here](conf_info)")
    }
    .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
        if url == URL(string: "conf_info") { // << intercept key
            showDetails()
            return .handled
        }
        return .systemAction
    })
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestTextWithButtonInside.swift)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a link in any `Text` view using Markdown's standard syntax, e.g.

```swift
Text("...For more information refer to [our privacy policy](https://example.org/privacy)")
```

If your destination is a public URL then that is all you need to do – clicking on it will open the relevant page in Safari.

However, if you want the click to be handled inside your app, you will need to pass the text view a custom `OpenURLAction`. See [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70155939/is-it-possible-to-open-a-markdown-link-in-our-app-instead-of-safari/70157033#70157033) on how to start going about that.