# SwifUI: How to have different text (size + color) in a SwiftUI Text string and not cause line breaking oddities on maximum accessibility sizes

Tags: swiftui

I'm Having a text view with custom font and color. One of them is a button label. I put them into an HStack for horizontal alignment. However, the text breaks oddly when the text size gets bigger.

[image]

The below image is what im trying to create.
[image]

This is my current code, I've tried .allowsTightening(true) or .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false) but nothing works out

```
        HStack(spacing: Constants.horizontalGap4){
        Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "square")
            .foregroundColor(isChecked ? Color(UIColor.systemBlue) : Color.secondary)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isChecked.toggle()
            }
        ActionTinyTextView(text: "I agree with the ", color: Color.gray)
            .allowsTightening(true)
        Button {                
        } label: {                
            ActionTinyTextView(text: CRContent.termAndConditionText)
                .allowsTightening(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look up attributed string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be used markdown, like

```
Text("I agree with [Terms & Use](link1) and [Privacy Policy](link2)")
  .foregroundColor(.gray) // << for main text
  .tint(.green)    // << your color for active text
```

[image: demo]

For such action links handling see my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72798487/12299030

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the `+` operator for `Text` view.

As long as you will be using only the `modifiers` which have a **Text** return type, this will solve your problem. Sample code and image are below:

[image]

```
struct SampleView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack { //from here
            Text("I agree with the ")
                .foregroundColor(.white) + //this
            Text("Terms & Use")
                .foregroundColor(.teal)
                .fontWeight(.bold) + //this
            Text(" and ")
                .foregroundColor(.white) + //this
            Text("Privacy Policy.")
                .foregroundColor(.teal)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
        .frame(width: 180)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the answer which I search from the last 10 days.

Comment: How can we handle taps on Text in such case?