# SwiftUI: How to open links in app instead of Safari using AttributedString

Tags: ios, url, swiftui, nsattributedstring

I have a FAQ page with cells that have a title as a String and a description as an AttributedString so that I can customize the appearance of the link in description. How can I open a link in an app instead of Safari? I also have a support mail link and I want to provide MailView to users.

```
struct LinkFormatter {
    
    static func toAS(for string: String, linkRange: String, to link: String) -> AttributedString{
        var result = AttributedString(string)
        
        let linkRange = result.range(of: linkRange)!
        
        result[linkRange].link = URL(string: link)
        result[linkRange].underlineStyle = Text.LineStyle(pattern: .solid)
        result[linkRange].foregroundColor = .black
        
        return result
    }
}

struct faqCell : View {

var mediumLink = LinkFormatter.toAS(for: "you can always read our Medium blog.",
                                    linkRange: "Medium blog",
                                    to: "https://medium.com")
    var body : some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("title")
            Text(mediumLink)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to open a markdown link in our app instead of Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70155939/is-it-possible-to-open-a-markdown-link-in-our-app-instead-of-safari)

Answer (score 0):

There's an environment handler you can use.

```
Text(mediumLink)
    .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
        // Do whatever

        return .handled
    })
```